# Hook into PHPUnit overall test state at runtime

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit bootstrap file that creates a test DB used for DB-related unit tests, and registers a shutdown function to destroy the DB once the tests complete. A fresh database for every run!

The problem: when tests fail, I want to hold onto the database for debugging purposes. At present, I have to manually disable my `register_shutdown_function()` call and then rerun the tests.

**If I could access PHPUnit's final success/fail state for the run, I could dynamically trigger the database destruction process based on a switch within the PHPUnit bootstrap file.**

PHPUnit stores this info somewhere in order to trigger the proper outcome event, i.e. the output `OK` vs `FAILURES!`. However from what I've uncovered, this information is not exposed to a user-level bootstrap file. Anyone ever done anything like this?

If you want to explore, here's a stack trace of PHPUnit that occurs when you run PHPUnit from the command line...

```
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:139
PHP   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:620
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:867
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
PHP   8. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95
PHP   9. [YOUR PHPUNIT BOOTSTRAP RUNS HERE]
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap the php unit script and look at its exit code?

Comment: The bootstrap (and indeed, all of our tests) get loaded in the middle of PHPUnit execution. You're deeper in the hierarchy, and never actually "touch" PHPUnit script internals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For accessing the state of PHPUnit test cases I usually recommend using:

See the docs: [`PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php) and [how to add it to the xml config](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners).

A small sample:

#### Extending the XML File with this

```
<listeners>
 <listener class="DbSetupListener" file="/optional/path/to/DbSetupListener.php"/>
</listeners>
```

#### Sample Listener

```
<?php
class DbSetupListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener {
    private $setupHappend = false;

    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) {
        $this->error = true;
    }

    public function addFailure(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time) {
        $this->error = true;
    }

    public function addIncompleteTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) { }
    public function addSkippedTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) { }
    public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test) { }
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time) { }

    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        if(!$this->setupHappend) { 
            $this->setupDatabase();
            $this->setupHappend = true;
        }
    }

    public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite) {
        // If you have multiple test suites this is the wrong place to do anything
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if($this->error) {
            // Something bad happend. Debug dump or whatever
        } else {
            // Teardown
        }
    }

}
```

This should get you going rather easy. If you need to only "listen" to specific `tests` or `testsuites` then you can use the parameters of `startTest` and `startTestSuite`.

Both objects have a `getName()` method that gives you the name of the test suite and test case respectively.

Comment: Clarification: does the listener __destruct() occur at the end of every test suite, or the entire run? We use a single DB for all test suites; DB only gets set up/torn down once.

Comment: Listener `__destruct()` only occurs once at the end of the last test suite. You could also move the `setupDatabase();` code to the listener `__construct()` that also only occurs once for all test suites.

Comment: My `register_shutdown_function` hack handled PHP-level errors, but this is really close, and doesn't require me to mess with the PHPUnit core. Thanks!